# как сделать движение мыши более плавным?

Tags: python, pyautogui

по быстрому написал код который записывает корды в текстовик,нужно это для задания траектории движения мыши с имитацией человека.

```
e = '\n'
while l < 50:
    x =(pyautogui.position())
    print(x)
    x =str(x)
    fo = open('total.txt', "r+")
    print('total.txt', fo.name)
    seq = x
    fo.seek(0, 2)
    x = fo.writelines(seq + e)
    fo.seek(0, 0)
    fo.close()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    l = l + 1
```

код можете смело брать если кому понадобится ,но применив это огромное количество координат понял что движения получаются пусть и по траектории но рывками можно ли передвижение от координаты до координаты сделать более плавным?

Comment: Поставить задержку между записями поменьше? 100мс это очень много, некоторые компьютерные игры имеют задержку меньше 1мс

Comment: Вообще, частота среднестатистического монитора 60 Гц, значит задержка должна быть никак не больше 16мс